# Python3(Tkinter) highlight text on focus

Tags: tkinter, python-3.7

I'm trying to figure out how to highlight the text in my text widget that I have focus set to. So the users can just click on the app, type, then hit enter without having to click to highlight to change the text. Anyone know if this can be done?

Current GUI:

````
    window.geometry('375x125')
    window.title("VPLS Lookup Tool")
    version = Label(window, text='VPLS Lookup Tool v.1.1')
    version.grid(column=1, row=0)
    vplsnumber = Label(window, text='VPLS Number:')
    vplsnumber.grid(column=0, row=1)
    vpls = Entry(window,width=10)
    vpls.focus_set()
    vpls.grid(column=1, row=1)
    #Placing the button and what specifying what to do when clicked
    btn = Button(window, text="Navigate to File", command=clicked)
    btn.grid(column=1, row=2)
    addpath = Button(window, text="Mount K Drive", command=clicked2)
    addpath.grid(column=1, row=3)
    window.bind('<Return>', Keyboard_Entry)
    window.bind('<KP_Enter>', Keyboard_Entry)
    window.mainloop()```
````

Comment: When you say "text widget", do you really mean an `Entry` widget? I don't see anywhere in the code where you create a `Text` widget.

Comment: Please create a proper [mcve]. The code you posted won't run for at least a half dozen reasons.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question you want to use the method `select_range`.  This selects the characters of text ready to replace, delete or copy.  It's included in a callback function to `<FocusIn>`

```
import tkinter as tk

def select_on_focus(event):
    event.widget.select_range(0, tk.END) # Select all the text in the widget.

root = tk.Tk()

ent = tk.Entry(root)
ent.grid()
ent.focus_set()
ent.insert(0, 'abcde')
ent.bind('<FocusIn>', select_on_focus)

root.mainloop()
```